# Remove empty attribute bindings in Ember components

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to make an Ember Component for clickable icons in a new project (an getting to know Ember in the process) and have run into an issue with attribute bindings:

How do I remove empty attribute bindings from the rendered HTML?

According to the official guides I can either bind to a string or number to let the attribute be poppulated with the string/number or bind to a boolean to toggle the attribute (assuming attributes and class names follow the same structure), but if I pass a boolean false to remove the attribute, its value is just set to the string "false".

**Component code**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'i',
  classNameBindings: ['icon'],
  attributeBindings: ['title', 'roleAttribute:role'],
  icon: 'blank', // Defaults to a blank icon
  title: '', // Defualts to empty title
  click() {
    this.sendAction();
  },
  roleAttribute: function() {
    return this.get('action') ? 'button' : false;
  }.property()
});
```

**Usage in template**

```
{{ui-icon icon="close" title="Close" action="hide"}}
{{ui-icon icon="close" title="Close"}}
```

**Expected result** (Ember ID's and class names removed for clarity)

```
<i role="button" title="Close" class="close"></i>
<i title="Close" class="close"></i>
```

**Real result** (Ember ID's and class names removed for clarity)

```
<i role="button" title="Close" class="close"></i>
<i role="false" title="Close" class="close"></i>
```

If I pass an empty string instead of false I still get the role, but without a value assigned, but I want no role at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on **[this comment](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/9595#issuecomment-66532025)** in the issue thread you should return `null` instead of `false` to remove an attribute.

**[Here is the working demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yugicom/1/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: I've updated the Ember Guide to include this: https://github.com/emberjs/guides/commit/3772445c406519a07ba1f1de6d3c5dbf3ab7cbe1